# integrate $\frac 1{x^2 + i}$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I have a question regarding this complex integral. How do I calculate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 + i} \,{\rm d}x?$$ I keep getting the result $0$ and most probably doing it the wrong way.

Comment: and for $i$ we have $$i^2=-1$$?

Comment: the x which solve $x^2+i=0$ are your residues. then pick a trajectory to integrate and check which residue is inside (important!)

Comment: the result should be $$1/2\,\pi \,\sqrt {2}-i/2\pi \,\sqrt {2}$$

Comment: then the right result really is 0? I came to the same result.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner epic finding

Comment: "then the right result really is 0?" No because $1 \neq i$

Comment: I read 1 instead of i, I'm sorry. how did you get to that result? my 2 residues are radical(2)/(2*(-1+i)) and radical(2)/(2*(1 - i))

Comment: The poles are 

$$z = \pm e^{3\pi i /4}$$

Comment: $$\mathrm{Res}(f,e^{3\pi i/4}) = -\frac{1+i}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. *Alternatively*, one may observe that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^4}\:dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+2}\:\frac{dx}{x^2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+2}\:dx=\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}
$$similarly
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}\:dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+2}\:dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+2}\:dx=\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}
$$ then, by writing
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+i}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2-i}{x^4-i^2}\:dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2\:dx}{1+x^4}-i\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^4}
$$ one may conclude with the preceding identities.

Answer (score 2):

An efficient approach is to use the Residue Theorem.  Proceeding, we have immediately

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+i}\,dx7&=2\pi i\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^2+i}, z=e^{i3\pi/4}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \frac{1}{-2e^{-i\pi/4}}\\\\
&=-\pi e^{i3\pi/4}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}(1-i)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Zaid; nice catch.  I've edited.  Thank you my friend!  -Mark

Comment: You are welcome , (+1).